# Are there any means currently for performing service discovery (mDNS or unicast DND-SD) in nanoframework?

Tags: esp32, mdns, dns-sd, nanoframework

I'm just wondering if there are any means of service discovery built into the nanoframework?

I am mainly interested in mDNS or unicast DNS service discovery. Think Apple Bonjour/Avahi.

I noticed Espressif has some arduino examples around mDNS.

https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/a59eafbc9dfa3ce818c110f996eebf68d755be24/libraries/ESPmDNS/examples/mDNS-SD_Extended/mDNS-SD_Extended.ino

It would make sense as a separate deployment use case when you don't want to connect to a hub in the cloud but instead have the hub (MQTT server) running on the local network and need to discover it.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no support for mDNS in .NET nanoFramework.
But that doesn't seem overcomplicated to add. Please raise an issue with the feature suggestion on our GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

Update 01-01-2023:
Support for mDNS in .NET nanoframework was requested in https://github.com/nanoframework/Home/issues/912. In that discussion, https://github.com/karlredgate/mDNS-sharp was recommended as an alternative to having it built-in into .NET nanoframework. It is not clear whether people succeeded with that, though.

Answer (score -1):

Welcome Cristian!

On an `ESP32` you can include `multicast DNS` and `DNS-Service Discovery` like that:

```
#include <ESPmDNS.h>
...
if (MDNS.begin("esp32")) { // access this ESP32 via http://esp32 (eg in browser)
    Serial.println("mDNS responder started");
}
...
// register a http-service in DNS-SD
if (mdns_service_add("esp32_website", "_http", "_tcp", 80, NULL, 0)) {
    Serial.println("DNS-SD responder started");
}
mdns_service_txt_item_set("esp32_website", "_http._tcp", "version", "1.0");
```

In order to actually discover the `ESP32` and it's services you need to make sure that the machine you are working on supports `mDNS` and `DNS-SD`.

Note: `mDNS` just "resolves" the name of the `ESP` to it's IP. You need to set-up a webserver on it to actually DO something (like provide the `DNS-SD`-promised website or such)

Comment: The question was specifically about .NET nanoframework. Cristian shared that he already found the Arduino sample, so this answer is less relevant to the question.